# Azure Functions - SQL DB Extract to Output Blob

Tags: c#, sql, blob, extract, azure-functions

I make reference to the below solution that I found on Stack. It's pretty close to what I am attempting to do but after a week of trying various options I am no closer.

I am attempting to write an Azure Function that will extract all the data from Azure Database and output the results to Blob Storage..

Below is my attempt. After exhausting all others, admittedly I'm not great at C# so it's probably my shortcoming. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Azure Function:

```cs
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"

using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public static void Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */30 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, 
    [Blob("mycontainer/myblob.txt", FileAccess.Write)] out string OutputBlob, 
    TraceWriter log)
{

   SqlDataReader rdr = null;

   var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb_connection"].ConnectionString;

   using (var conn = new SqlConnection(str))
   {
        conn.Open();

        // Query Text
        var text = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Kpi";

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            // Execute the command 
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var csv = new StringBuilder();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                // get the results of each column
                string FirstName = (string)rdr["FirstName"];
                string LastName = (string)rdr["LastName"];

                // create a string
                var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", FirstName, LastName);
                csv.AppendLine(newLine);
            }

            // How do I get the results to the outputBlob ??
            File.WriteAllText(outputBlob, csv.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1 --->
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException : Script
>   compilation failed. at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 340 at async

[Error Message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YVWp.png)

[Solution Found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177915/azure-function-to-connect-to-both-blob-and-sql-storage)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Apologies, here is the error below

Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1 ---> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException : Script compilation failed.
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 340
   at async

Comment: Is it the complete callstack? Looks like something is missing...

Comment: I've attached the error message image, any ideas? I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using binding attributes in C# script, which is wrong... The referenced solution is using precompiled .NET project, not script.

When using script, make sure that your `function.json` file looks like this:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "schedule": "0 */30 * * * *",
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "OutputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "mycontainer/myblob.txt",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

then remove attributes from Function definition:

```cs
public static void Run(
    TimerInfo myTimer, 
    out string OutputBlob, 
    TraceWriter log)
```

and finally assign the blob content directly in the end of the call

```cs
// ... 
            OutputBlob = csv.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Overall, my advice is to move to precompiled C# project (as the one in the question you referenced). That takes some setup (in Visual Studio or VS Code) but it will help you avoid the issues and find the errors faster and more exactly.

Comment: Wow, fantastic, that has worked an absolute treat. Thank you so much for your time, pointers and tips. Are there any reference books you can recommend for a beginner like myself?

Comment: @BillyB Great to hear! I don't know any reference books, you should spend time reading the docs, but I do realize they are fragmented and sometimes confusing. People ask lots of questions on stack overflow. Btw feel free to upvote the answer too ;)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the advice, I will do. I've tried to up vote but I only joined yesterday and doesn't look i got enough reputations.. less than 15 don't count it says :-(
Soon as I am over the 15 threshold that will definitely get my vote, and once again massive Thank You

Comment: @BillyB Haha, that's nice of you. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just assign it. Output blob is a string:

```
           OutputBlob= csv.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.. 
Tried it and still getting error as per above.. 
Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1 ---> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException : Script compilation failed.
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 340